# How to make a script run at boot?

Tags: scripts, android, vnc, restart

i have a VNC set up with my phone because i use Linux for some things android cant do.
i would like to know how to restart the computer from my phone without having to go to my computer and physically type the commands.

sudo -s

export DISPLAY=:0.0

xhost +

/usr/lib/vino/vino-server &

i tried Google but i couldn't find anything any help would be nice.

---

i did the Terminal thing but it didnt work it looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
/home/jonluke/SSH.sh &
exit 0
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start VNC at boot, save your script to a location on disk as a `.sh`, run `chmod a+x yourscriptname` in a terminal (to make it executable) and add it to /etc/rc.local;

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/path/to/your/script &

exit 0
```

Note the trailing `&` and the final `exit 0`; this will run the script and then continue the boot process and not block anything.

Comment: where do i put chmod a+x

Comment: I have updated my post; essentially you create the file and then `chmod a+x yourscriptname.sh` from a terminal to make that script executable.

Comment: You run `chmod a+x /path/to/your/file`. You only need to do it once after you create it to make sure it is executable

Comment: Also, you may have problems with a script that includes sudo commands since it will expect a password. You can edit your `/etc/sudoers` file using `sudo visudo` to allow you to run the specific commands you need as sudo without needing a password. There are a number of questions that address doing this if you search for "editing /etc/sudoers nopasswd"

Comment: i already have that i set that up as soon as i reinstalled UBUNTU a few weeks ago. but the commands dont work .-.